# Draw rotated and scaled UILabel text inside UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage, uilabel

I have one `UIScrollView` with a `UIImageView` inside from where I obtain a cropped UIImage (considering scale, offset, bounds,...). On the other hand, I have a `UILabel` which I can rotate, pinch and pan anywhere over the `UIScrollView`. The problem comes when I try to generate the final image with the label text inside (with it's original/equivalent position, rotation,...) on the cropped `UIImage` (bigger than screen size).

I've tried everything. This is my last attempt trying to position the text, but it's always misplaced.

```
// Compute rect to draw the text inside
CGSize imageSize = inImage.size;
NSDictionary *attr = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fontColor, NSFontAttributeName: textFont};
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:attr];
CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(labelCenterPoint.x, labelCenterPoint.y, textSize.width, textSize.height);

// Create the image
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
[inImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];

// Rotate text from center
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0.5f * textSize.width, 0.5f * textSize.height ) ;
CGContextRotateCTM(context, rotation);
[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(textRect) withAttributes:attr];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I think the problem is the `textRect` origin. Do I have to make the `UILabel` a `subView` of the `UIScrollView` too and make the `textRect` origin relative to the `UIScrollView` parameters? or am I missing something?. Is there a better way?.

Thanks in advance!.

**Edit:**
I have finally found an acceptable solution (although is not too much precise). I think the problem was about the two existing coordinate systems, so I tried a different approach:

```
    // Calculate the relative position of the UILabel with respect 
    // to the ScrollView that contains the image
    float xPosition = label.frame.origin.x - scrollView.frame.origin.x;
    float yPosition = label.frame.origin.y - scrollView.frame.origin.y;
    // Calculate the proportion to apply to the position 
    // (the image is bigger than screen)
    float xProportion = image.frame.size.width / scrollView.frame.size.width;
    float yProportion = image.frame.size.height / scrollView.frame.size.height;

    UIImageView *testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
            CGRectMake((xPosition*xProportion), 
                       (yPosition*yProportion),            
                       label.frame.size.width*xProportion, 
                       label.frame.size.height*yProportion)];
    tempLabel.text = label.text;
    tempLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:label.font.fontName 
                                     size:label.font.pointSize*3];
    tempLabel.textColor = label.textColor;
    tempLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    tempLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
    tempLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    tempLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.05;

    [testView addSubview:tempLabel];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(testView.image.size);
    [testView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *imageWithText = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

I hope this may help someone. All suggestions are welcome of course.